# Cannot change deffault gui frame icon in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, icons

#Java#JavaGUI
Hi I'm Nick , I'm coding in Jva and I can't change the deffault frame icon in a GUI frame I created.
Now I will tell you about the code I wrote in VS Code while trying to change the deffault frame icon in a GUI frame I created in VS Code . The code is exactly the same as in the video by channel Bro Code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xk4_1vDrzzo with time stamp: 5:32:18.

Here's the code I tried and which I expected to do the work :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();//creates a frame
        frame.setTitle("JFrame title goes here");//This sets frame's title
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//exit out of application
        frame.setResizable(false);//prevent frame from being resized
        frame.setSize(420,420);//sets x-dimension and y-dimension
        frame.setVisible(true);//make frame visible

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("classybrocode.jpg");
        frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());//change icon of frame

    }
}
```

Comment: I actually runned from the  VS Code Terminal and it worked . I set the directory to the src  file of the project and it worked just fine

Comment: Good....now will it work when it's a JAR file and run on its own **somewhere** (without the IDE)?